# Instalar Prolog en Visual Studio Code y su uso MacM1

Tags: visual-studio, macos, prolog

Cuando en Visual Studio Code instalo Prolog , me sale :

*"Cannot lint the prolog file. The Prolog executable was not found. Use the 'prolog.executablePath' setting to configure"*

Si alguien me podría decir que puedo hacer .

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ya esta !
He encontrado que para solucionarlo hay que ir en VSCode  a configuración o  `⌘,` y en el buscador ponemos Prolog , buscamos el apartado `Prolog: Executable Path Points to the Prolog executable.` allí aparece una ruta , pero borramos esa ruta y en ella ponemos la ruta donde está instalado Prolog en nuestro ordenador .
Para saber donde está la ruta , si eres principiante como yo , suelo abrir textEdit y en un nuevo documento , al crearlo , pinchamos en `formato>convertir a texto sin formato`  , ahora lo que hacemos es buscar la aplicación en Finder y arrastrar Prolog al documento , y ya nos aparecería la ruta .